# How to fold arrays in the editor Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to set change the Android Studio editor settings so that when I press format it doesn't place each element in the array in a new line as seen on this screenshot:

[Android Studio array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPPk5.png)

But folds it nicely, like Rider does seen in the following screenshot:

[Rider array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikA5.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the difference is due to languages (**Kotlin vs Java**), and not IDEs (**Android Studio vs Rider**). The culprit of your formatting problem is Kotlin's language feature to use `arrayOf()` function instead of array initializer to create arrays with known list of elements. Elements in `arrayOf(...)` are considered **Function call arguments**, so you may want to look at the corresponding setting.

In File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Wrappings and Braces, the default value of `Function call arguments` is `Do not wrap`. This means the formatter **respects your code** and will never add new lines between arguments. Option `Wrap if long` means if one line exceeds hard wrap limit (default: 120 chars), `\n` or `\n\r` will be inserted. I think switching to this option is one thing you can do but wrapping at 120 chars may be too long for arrays. The other options, in my opinion, don't help much in your case.

By comparsion, Java has an extra `Array initializer` setting in `Wrappings and Braces` section.

As I have said, the formatter respects your code. Since "one element in one line" doesn't violate your wrapping rule, your code doesn't get reformatted. You can manually edit your code by **searching and replacing** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on Windows, possibly <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on macOS) related lines using regular expressions :-)